# Converting .docx that includes tables, images and citations to latex without manual editing?

Tags: tables

Potential Solutions I've Explored:

- Pandoc: doesn't seem to work well with tables in docx
- Libre office word2latex
- Table generator: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#

Does there exist one solution that converts a document with tables and images to a latex file without having to use multiple solutions together? I want to minimize the total work I have do since I have a 300 page thesis in .docx that I need to convert to latex.

I've also noticed that I have to save each image, put it in a folder and then render the latex from the word document.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.  What is "this" in "a 300 page this"?

Comment: my bad just fixed that typo

Comment: I think this eternally asked question hasn't gotten a no-look-back answer. No easy way to go from one format to the other as far as I know.